# Flutter: KeyboardType attribute not working as expected in TextFormField ,still can paste text.how to change input type?(Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

I am using a TextFormField to get a number as input so i used this snippet

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
```

This is my TextFormField Widget code

```
         TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  style: textstyle,
                  controller: principal,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Please enter principal amount e.g 3245";
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Principal",
                      labelStyle: textstyle,
                      hintText: "Rupees",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                )
```

But now i can paste some text in the same field as shown here[image]

So now how can i format my TextFormfield to restrict to type only number & to restrict pasting texts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer is now deprecated as of Flutter version 1.20.0-1.0.pre. Now, use `inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],` instead [(see documentation)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter/digitsOnly.html).

In addition, if you want finer control onto what to input using RegEx, use `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'your regex here'))`.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Deprecated API removed after v2.5

**Old answer**

You can try to use `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter`
like

`inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],`

See official [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter-class.html)

Comment: This solution works, provided need to import   `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`